# jsPdf link to current document

Tags: angular, hyperlink, jspdf

In **Angular** using [**jspdf**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf), While creating a PDF, I want to add an index page with links to different pages within the same document.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.